# error using typedef inside class template

Tags: c++

I have a queue/stack program based off of a linkedlist that I'm trying to convert into templates (I have .h and corresponding .template files for Queue, Stack, LinkedList and Node). However when I try to instantiate the queue gcc is throwing this error:

```
LinkedList.template: In instantiation of ‘class LinkedList<int>’:
Queue.h:11:45:   required from ‘class Queue<int>’
Grades.cpp:15:13:   required from here
LinkedList.template:66:6: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class node<int>’
 void LinkedList<value_type>::addToHead(typename node<value_type>::value_type& entry)
```

This is my instantiation that's referenced in the error although I don't think it's the problem:

```
void LinkedList<value_type>::addToHead(typename node<value_type>::value_type& entry)
{
    head = new node<value_type>(entry, head);
    if (tail == NULL) {tail = head;}
    current = head;
}
```

This is my typedef declaration for value_type:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
    public:
    typedef typename LinkedList<T>::value_type value_type;
    ...
}
```

Is this the correct way to use typedef for what I'm trying to do? It's supposed to get the template type from LinkedList.h:

```
template <typename value_type>
class LinkedList
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're using `node<value_type>::value_type`, did you define `value_type` in `node`?

Answer (score 0):

The name of a template argument is not visible outside of the template. You need a typedef to provide that name:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
typedef T value_type;
...
};
```